# Qt5 C++: Custom Spinbox accepting two values

Tags: c++, qt, widget

I'm not really into qt but i would like to have spinbox accepting two values
i.e:

[image]

It should work like this: select value to change with mouse f.e second value click arrow button and change this value.

Is there any possibility to do that, not creating a new own custom widget?

Comment: wouldnt you need two spinners to enable changing both values?

Comment: I want one custom spinbox because i'm adding it to a tree. It will be more flexible and ellegant

Comment: What tobi303 means is that you would need to pairs of arrow buttons to change the two values... Or what do you expect it to do when clicking on the arrow-up-button in this case? Change to `5 to 6`? How do you then change it to `6 to 6`?

Comment: if you want to change two values, use two spinboxes, anything else will be just confusing

Comment: @mistgun When you're asked for clarification, please edit your question with missing information, instead of replying in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is: no

Long answer is:

You should subclass `QAbstractSpinBox` and implement these two virtual methods:

```
virtual void stepBy(int steps) override;
virtual StepEnabled stepEnabled() const override;
```

**Keep in mind that you will need to provide your own data store and data manipulation!**

The first function determines what happens when the step in either direction is requested. The negative number for steps (that tells how many steps to go in either direction) means go down and positive means up (i.e. clicking on the arrows of the SpinBox). `QSpinBox` adds the value in `steps` to its value (so when negative it gets subtracted) for example. Here you can also catch what part of the SpiBox's string the user selected and increment that appropriately with use of

```
lineEdit()->selectionStart(); 
lineEdit()->selectedText();
```

and when you are done you set the correct text back with:

```
lineEdit()->setText(myModifedValueText); //note that your internally stored value does not need to be QString, you just need to create it from your value in this method to set it to the internal QLineEdit so it can be displayed
```

The second method is called when the SpinBox needs to know if it can go up or down. So basically here you check the boundaries (if there are any) and return the appropriate flags (`QAbstractSpinBox::StepUpEnabled` or `QAbstractSpinBox::StepDownEnabled` or both).

Optinally in the constructor of your SpinBox you can apply `QValidator` to its internal `QLineEdit` to accept only certain format of values when the user inputs them by hand, e.g.:

```
QRegExpValidator *validator = new QRegExpValidator(this);
validator->setRegExp(...); //create a RegExp for your value, you may use any Online regexp validator/creator for this to get the right one
lineEdit()->setValidator(validator);
```

Finally you can fine-tune your SpinBox to show a text when there is an invalid value or you can fix it yourself using `QAbstractSpinBox::fixup` and validate the input with the namesake `QAbstractSpinBox::validate`.

For really pimped out SpinBox you could also re-implement its context menu and actions where you first get the standard menu from `QLineEdit`:

```
QMenu *menu = lineEdit()->createStandardContextMenu();
```

in the `QWidget::contextMenuEvent` and add/modify it as you need before you show it with `menu->exec(event->globalPos())` and then `delete menu;`.

**However `QAbstractSpinBox` does most of the ground job for you so you really should be fine with implementing just the above two virtual methods.**

Comment: You skipped over the most important and involved detail: how to draw such a widget properly, i.e. while maintaining styling. What you describe is perhaps the simplest part of it all, almost an afterthought.

Comment: @KubaOber Perhaps I do not understand what drawing is involved here? The QAbstractSpinBox draws only the internal QLineEdit (just like any line edit) and that can be set to whatever QLineEdit subclass one desires and styled like any widget. Atop of that it draws the "arrows" for handling it and what they appear is handled via QAbstractSpinBox::ButtonSymbols enum and those can be styled as well (see Qt's stylesheet docs, i.e. ::down-button, ::down-arrow etc.).

Comment: Ah, OK, if we're to keep it drawn the same, then sure, all that changes is the numerical-to-text conversion and the stateful behavior of the buttons. You're right.